# libvirt timing out. parted blocked messages in kern.log

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, kvm-virtualization, libvirt

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS to host KVM virtual machines. I'm using eucalyptus to manage them and having a lot of issues with libvirt not being able to interface with the KVM components and timing out. This is causing Eucalyptus to think the instances are dead.

Noticing a lot of these messages in the kern.log. Can anyone help me determine what these mean?

```
May  5 03:57:03 [host] kernel: [3638726.030567] INFO: task parted:24773 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
May  5 03:57:03 [host] kernel: [3638726.030828] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
May  5 03:57:03 [host] kernel: [3638726.042960] parted        D 00000000ffffffff     0 24773  24772 0x00000000
May  5 03:57:03 [host] kernel: [3638726.042969]  ffff880e119add28 0000000000000082 0000000000015f00 0000000000015f00
May  5 03:57:03 [host] kernel: [3638726.042976]  ffff8815d00c9ad0 ffff880e119adfd8 0000000000015f00 ffff8815d00c9700
May  5 03:57:03 [host] kernel: [3638726.042983]  0000000000015f00 ffff880e119adfd8 0000000000015f00 ffff8815d00c9ad0
May  5 03:57:03 [host] kernel: [3638726.042990] Call Trace:
May  5 03:57:03 [host] kernel: [3638726.043004]  [<ffffffff8155866d>] schedule_timeout+0x22d/0x300
May  5 03:57:03 [host] kernel: [3638726.043012]  [<ffffffff81100a45>] ? pagevec_lookup_tag+0x25/0x40
May  5 03:57:03 [host] kernel: [3638726.043017]  [<ffffffff810ff8af>] ? write_cache_pages+0xef/0x3e0
May  5 03:57:03 [host] kernel: [3638726.043023]  [<ffffffff810fe800>] ? __writepage+0x0/0x40
May  5 03:57:03 [host] kernel: [3638726.043026]  [<ffffffff815577e6>] wait_for_common+0xd6/0x180
May  5 03:57:03 [host] kernel: [3638726.043031]  [<ffffffff8105dd7b>] ? try_to_wake_up+0x2fb/0x480
May  5 03:57:03 [host] kernel: [3638726.043035]  [<ffffffff8105df00>] ? default_wake_function+0x0/0x20
May  5 03:57:03 [host] kernel: [3638726.043039]  [<ffffffff8155794d>] wait_for_completion+0x1d/0x20
May  5 03:57:03 [host] kernel: [3638726.043047]  [<ffffffff81169361>] writeback_inodes_sb+0xb1/0xe0
May  5 03:57:03 [host] kernel: [3638726.043052]  [<ffffffff8116e09e>] __sync_filesystem+0x3e/0x90
May  5 03:57:03 [host] kernel: [3638726.043056]  [<ffffffff8116e1c9>] sync_filesystems+0xd9/0x130
May  5 03:57:03 [host] kernel: [3638726.043061]  [<ffffffff8116e277>] sys_sync+0x17/0x40
May  5 03:57:03 [host] kernel: [3638726.043068]  [<ffffffff810131b2>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
```

Running

libvirt-bin                     0.7.5-5ubuntu27.22

qemu-kvm                        0.12.3+noroms-0ubuntu9.18

Comment: How's your storage sub-system doing? Last time I saw those messages, the server's 3ware RAID was slowly dying.

Comment: It's running on a single SSD for the root filesystem, and the other mounted filesystem is a SAN connnected over iSCSI